# InvalidClientTokenId error when using aws cli with Calgary(ca-west-1) as the default region

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

`aws rds describe-db-snapshots`

> An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the DescribeDBSnapshots operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.

I tried the same operation by changing the default region to us-east-1 and it works just fine. I also reconfigured the credentials but it did not help.

Comment: This is most likely due to your aws cli credentials. Ensure your AWS CLI has the appropriate credentials for your target region. If it operates correctly in `us-east-1` but fails in another, besides re-running `aws configure` to correctly establish your region, you can also explicitly specify the region in your command with `--region your_region`. For specific profiles, use `--profile profile_name`.